# Auto-updating BASH prompts with Mercurial repository info

Tags: bash, command-line, mercurial

I have followed the directions [outlined by Steve Losh](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/03/mercurial-bash-prompts/) to colorize and format my bash prompt, however, the prompt doesn't update.

My `export PS1` line looks like this:

```
export PS1="\n\[$txtgrn\]\w\[$txtrst\]$(hg_in_repo)\[$txtylw\]$(hg_branch)\[$txtrst\]$(hg_dirty)\n\[$txtcyn\]\$\[$txtrst\] "
```

Yes, all those `$txtxxx`'s are defined.

Everything works as expected, both inside and out of a repository, but I have to constantly `source ~/.bash_profile` to get the prompt to update.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to get it to update every time I execute a command, like he demonstrates in the screenshot further down the page?

I am using Mac OSX 10.5 (Leopard), with Terminal and/or iTerm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the dollar signs so the command substitution isn't evaluated until the prompt is issued:

```
export PS1="\n\[$txtgrn\]\w\[$txtrst\]\$(hg_in_repo)\[$txtylw\]\$(hg_branch)\[$txtrst\]\$(hg_dirty)\n\[$txtcyn\]\$\[$txtrst\] "
```

Or, if you notice on that page, he uses single quotes which also prevents expansion of the command substitution until the prompt is issued:

```
export PS1='\n\[$txtgrn\]\w\[$txtrst\]$(hg_in_repo)\[$txtylw\]$(hg_branch)\[$txtrst\]$(hg_dirty)\n\[$txtcyn\]\$\[$txtrst\] '
```